# Center content in android 4.4 webview

Tags: css, google-chrome, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm displaying mathematical expressions in a webview (using jqmath library and some CSS). One requirement is that expressions should be centred, and here's what I use to achieve that:

```
<html><head><style type='text/css'>html,body {margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;}html {display: table;}body {display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;}</style></head><body><p>here goes the expression</p></body></html>
```

Since rendering math takes some time, the webview is hidden while the expression is rendering, and displayed only when it is ready (once the WebViewClient's `onPageFinished` has been called). This worked well until Android 4.4.

The problem with the new webview seems to be that it only applies CSS when it is visible on screen. So after revealing the hidden webview, the expression first appears in the top left corner, and only after ~0.1 seconds "jumps" to the center. This looks ugly, since I have to display many expressions in quick succession.

A related problem is described in this question: [width:100% in CSS not rendering well in Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810629/width100-in-css-not-rendering-well-in-android-4-4). The asker was able to solve his problem by removing the `display: table;` from html, but that doesn't work in my case.

So is there a way to either:
(a) force the new (Chromium-based) webview to render content while it is not visible, or
(b) display the content at the center from the beginning (without first displaying it in the top left corner).

Comment: What LayoutParams is your WebView attached to the View hierarchy with? How do you make it visible/invisible? Any other special configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that the KK WebView applies CSS only when visible on screen:

- the WebView will not size itself if it has visibility set to `GONE` because the Android framework will call layout-related methods on it (like `layout` and `onSizeChanged`). This might be what you're seeing. Try setting the visibility to `INVISIBLE` instead.
- `WebViewClient.onPageFinished` is not a reliable trigger for showing your WebView. What the callback really means is that the resource for the main frame had been loaded from the network. Unfortunately there never was a reliable callback that would tell you 'your content is ready to be displayed' - what you're describing probably happened to work because of particular timing. The most reliable way to not show unfinished content would be to do so in the HTML/CSS.
- you might be using `WebView.loadDataWithBaseUrl` to load your contents into a new/blank WebView - this API is has an effect similar to re-writing the page's content (rather than issuing a 'real' navigation) and can result in weird layout. If possible use `loadData` or `loadUrl`. If neither of those are feasible try calling `loadUrl("data:text/html,<body style=\"margin: 0px;\"/>");` before loading the real content (wait at least till you get an `WebViewClient.onPageStarted` callback for that bootstrap URL).
- you might be setting height to `WRAP_CONTENTS`. This is very unlikely to cause the issues you're describing, but it would be good to rule out. Try setting a width of `MATCH_PARENT` and a height with a fixed number of pixels.

Comment: Yes, your number 1 clue solved the problem. I had my webview wrapped in a fragment, and hid/showed that fragment as necessary with fragmentTransaction. However, fragmentTransaction's hide() method actually sets the fragment's view to GONE. So it is necessary to apply myFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) before loading any content. Interestingly, that was not necessary before KK.